# SwipeRefreshLayout return bug

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, swiperefreshlayout

I'm using a `SwipeRefeshLayout` with a `RecycleView` inside.
This `recycleView` contains `view-holders` that have a click function that changes the display. This works fine until I refresh the view multiple times.
For example: If I refresh it 5 times, click on a `viewholder`, I will have to click 5 times on the return button to return to the `recycleview` fragment.

The code:
HomeFragment.cs:

```
       private void HandleRefresh(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
        try
        {
            page = 0;
            adapter.clearMoments();
            RefreshData(adapter, 0);
            mySwipeRefreshLayout.Refreshing = false;
        }


        private async void RefreshData(MomentAdapterRV adapter, int page)
        {
        JsonValue json = await model.getMoments(page);
        try
        {
            InitData(adapter, json, page);
        }

        private void InitData(MomentAdapterRV adapter, JsonValue json, int pageNum)
    {
        var myActivity = (MainActivity)this.Activity;
        try
        {
            if (json.Count > 0)
            {               
                for (var i = 0; i < json.Count; i++)
                {                     
                    // Some code
                    adapter.addMoment(Moment moment)
                }
                   // Some code
            }
        }
```

MomentAdapterRV.cs:

```
    public MomentAdapterRV(Context context, List<Moment> items, MainActivity activity)
    {
        mItems = items;
        mContext = context;
        mActivity = activity;
        cb = CommunityBuilderModel.Instance;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is the constuctor function of this adapter where the given class arguments (streamFragment, Moments) are being passed to the class variables.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="streamFragement"></param>
    /// <param name="mItems"></param>
    public MomentAdapterRV(StreamFragment streamFragement, List<Moment> mItems)
    {
        this.streamFragement = streamFragement;
        this.mItems = mItems;
    }

    public void addMoment(Moment moment)
    {
        mItems.Add(moment);            
        NotifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void clearMoments()
    {
        mItems.Clear();
    }

    public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder
               OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).
                    Inflate(Resource.Layout.MomentListItem, parent, false);
        MomentViewHolder vh = new MomentViewHolder(itemView);
        return vh;
    }

    public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
         // Some code

        vh.llMain.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        {
            //Check if you don't get a negative position from the header.
            if (holder.AdapterPosition >= 0)
            {

                // Create a new fragment and a transaction.
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTx = mActivity.FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
                MomentFragment aDifferentDetailsFrag = new MomentFragment();

                // Some code

                // Replace the fragment that is in the View fragment_container (if applicable).
                fragmentTx.Replace(Resource.Id.frameLayout1, aDifferentDetailsFrag);

                // Add the transaction to the back stack.
                fragmentTx.AddToBackStack(null);

                // Commit the transaction.
                fragmentTx.Commit();

                //Put Argument
                aDifferentDetailsFrag.Arguments = utilBundle;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you assign the `Click` event in `OnBindViewHolder` and you never unsubscribe this click event.

So for each time you refresh your items in your RecyclerView, `OnBindViewHolder` is called. This will also happen if your list is longer than can be displayed on screen and you scroll up and down.

Instead you should assign the `Click` even in `OnCreateViewHolder` so it is only hooked up once, and not every time it is shown.